# Linked List understanding syntax

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, linked-list

```
1  struct node
2  {
3     int data;
4     struct node *next;
5  }*head;
6 
7  void append(int num)
8  {
9     struct node *temp,*right;
10    temp= (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
11    temp->data=num;
12    right=(struct node *)head;
13    while(right->next != NULL)
14        right=right->next;
15    right->next =temp;
16    right=temp;
17    right->next=NULL;
18 }
```

I need help understanding certain parts of this code.

1) What does is the code supposed to do?

2) What does line 5 do?

```
}*head;
```

Im used to seeing this when I make my structs:

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
```

3) What is line 12 supposed to do? not sure of this syntax

```
right=(struct node *)head;
```

My guess is that it takes what head is pointing to and makes right point to it too. So why not just do: `right = head;`

thanks!

Comment: Fyi, *neither* of the casts in this code are necessary. I'm constantly confounded by the propensity for people to enter unnecessary cruft in there code. Writing code that works is hard enough; littering it with unnecessary crap doesn't make it better.

Comment: And were I to do this, it would like [something like **this**](http://pastebin.com/FL6wrF9Z).  Different strokes for different folks, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

So, this may not be the most complete answer:
Regarding `}*head;`, this is just immediately declaring the head of the struct, an instance named head, which itself is a pointer to a struct instance.  Then, later, on line 12, with `right = (struct node *)head`, the pointer is being cast.  Perhaps this is for safety, or clarity; I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Line 5 declares a global variable `head` that is a pointer to the struct type declared before.

Line 12 assigns `head` to `right`. The cast is not necessary.

The function allocates a new node, gives the `data` member the value of `num`, goes to the end of the list and appends it.

```
15    right->next =temp;
16    right=temp;
17    right->next=NULL;
```

Line 15 appends the new node. Variable `right` is now available and `temp` is assigned to it. Line 16 now sets the `next` member of the last member of the list to null. These last two lines could simply have been written as `temp->next= NULL;`.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that makes sense.

Comment: I understand that from lines 13-14, we are trying to get to the end of the linked list, however what is the point of lines 15-17? 

I don't understand why you would first append temp to right->next, then append temp to right after, then make right->next = NULL.

Can't you just remove lines 15, because it's redundant?

Comment: Sorry, nvm I get it.

Line 15, appends temp to the end of the list
Line 16, makes right point to temp
Lines 17, makes what temp is pointing to null